# How do I assign any non-filled parts of my array with null characters, and then write it into a file?

Tags: c, null, fwrite

I'm trying to get the below function to place three things into a file: first, last, and ssn. First is 30 characters long, last is 30 characters long, and ssn is 9 characters long.

What I want to happen in the file is that I enter the following info:
first: john
last: smith
ssn: 123456789

this is what should load into the file (all one line):

john\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0smith\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0123456789

However, all that loads is usually john(junk)smith(junk)123456789.

How do I make it so that, when I write these 3 things into a file, they also have null characters in each un-used space?

```
void addStudents(struct student createStudent) {

    struct student *object = malloc( sizeof( struct student ) );

    memcpy(object->first, createStudent.first, 30);
    memcpy(object->last, createStudent.last, 30);
    memcpy(object->ssn, createStudent.ssn, 9);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("students.db", "a");

    fseek( fp, numStudents * sizeof( struct student ), SEEK_SET );
    fwrite( object, sizeof( struct student ), 1, fp );

}
```

This is the definition of the struct student:

```
struct student {
    char first[30];
    char last[30];
    char ssn[9];
};
```

EDIT: I want the null characters in the file. As in, to open the file and have it read exactly as "john\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0smith\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0123456789", null characters included. Is there no way to do this? I'd like to be able to access the file and effectively tell the program to "go back" 30 chars from the beginning of the ssn, to the beginning of the last name.

Strcpy and strncpy do fix the issue with the junk appearing, but they don't include the '\0' character in the file.

Comment: Use `strncpy` instead of `memcpy`.

Comment: How is your `struct student`  defined? As you are using `fwrite`.

Comment: Edited to include the definition. Also, tried using strncpy but it only printed johnsmith123456789 -- no nulls in the file.

Comment: There's really no need to initialize unused parts of your structure. There's also no need what so ever for the temporary `object` to be a pointer, or to exist at all.

Comment: ***However...*** There's one thing you *must* remember, and that is that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That means a string of nine characters needs space for *ten* to include the null terminator. Now think about that in relation to your `ssn` array.

Comment: Lastly remember, garbage in leads to garbage out. If your strings in the `createStudent` structure aren't properly null-terminated, then it doesn't really matter how you initialize or copy that structure, the strings will *always* lack the terminator.

Comment: You should not be opening the file with mode "a".

Comment: Better yet, serialize the data by writing an `int` containing the length of the string , and then only the characters of the string to the file. Then to read it back in, you read an `int`, then read that number of character (and *nul-terminate*), repeat until `EOF`. That way if your name has 3-chars, `"Jan"`, you write the `int` `3` and then `"Jan"`, etc.. (since all your names are less than 255-char, you can actually just use an `unsigned char` to hold the size rather than `int`)

Comment: @WilliamPursell What would be a better choice to open it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is using `fwrite()` to dump the structure (`struct student`) into a file.  `fwrite()` just writes a binary blob, it doesn't care about string-endings, or data initialisation.

You're getting lots of junk because the incoming `createStudent` structure contains lots of junk.  It has junk in it because C will not initialise members automatically (it's a waste of time).  If you want them "clean", you have to code it explicitly.

It's possible to clear the structure before the data is loaded into it with a call to the `memset()` function:

```
memset( object, 0, sizeof( *object ) );
```

Which will fill it full of 0 / NULLs.  Since C-strings are terminated with '\0' (binary 0) this clears the string arrays of all junk.  Note that it doesn't actually hurt your process if the written data has junk in it, so as long as the string terminator is preserved in the process.  An array `[abc\0some-junk]` just looks like "abc", when used as a string.

Anyway, so before the structure is initially written with data, initialise it.  The OP's code does not include this part, so I've worked it into the `addStudents()` function.  (And note: you aren't handling `numStudents` at all).

```
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 29  
#define MAX_SSN_SIZE   8

struct student 
{
    char first[ MAX_NAME_SIZE + 1 ];
    char last[ MAX_NAME_SIZE + 1 ];
    char ssn[ MAX_SSN_SIZE + 1 ];
};

void addStudents(struct student createStudent) 
{
    struct student *object = malloc( sizeof( struct student ) );

    if ( object != NULL )
    {    
        memset( object, 0, sizeof( *object ) );  // fill with \0

        // Note: string buffers zeroed and 1-char bigger, so strncpy() is safe
        strncpy( object->first, createStudent.first, MAX_NAME_SIZE );
        strncpy( object->last,  createStudent.last,  MAX_NAME_SIZE );
        strncpy( object->ssn,   createStudent.ssn,   MAX_SSN_SIZE );

        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("students.db", "a");
        if ( fp != NULL )
        {
            // TODO: check these functions don't return error
            fseek( fp, numStudents * sizeof( struct student ), SEEK_SET );  // Necessary when open "a"?
            fwrite( object, sizeof( struct student ), 1, fp );
            fclose( fp );  // Don't forget to close
        }
        else
        {
             // TODO: handle file error
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO - handle memory error
    }
}
```

You should consider writing the number of records into the top of the file, before all the record-bodies.  This allows you to read it, and update it easily.

Answer (score 0):

## use memset() and strcpy()

Place the following right after the `malloc()`:

`memset(object, 0, sizeof(struct student));`

and use `strcpy()` instead on `memcpy()`:

```
strcpy(object->first, createStudent.first);
strcpy(object->last, createStudent.last);
strcpy(object->ssn, createStudent.ssn);
```

This will nullify the entire struct and will only copy till the terminating null, assuming that `createStudent` has null terminated strings which are never longer than the defined related `object` ones (in case it is not, you can use `strncpy()`).

Comment: This helps, but I want the null characters in the file. As in, to open the file and have it read exactly as "john\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0smith\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0123456789", null characters included. Is there no way to do this? I'd like to be able to access the file and effectively tell the program to "go back" 30 chars from the beginning of the ssn, to the beginning of the last name.

Comment: This will do it as you asked. Try it out. Let me know if it didn't, I'll try to help further.

Comment: @StrugglingStudent ***Why***? What is the problem that is supposed to solve? As long as the strings are properly null-terminated, who cares what data follows the terminator? Your question now seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you have a solution you want help with, but you don't tell us what problem you're really trying to solve. What makes you think you need those zeros in the file?

Comment: @StrugglingStudent Also remember that arrays have a *fixed size*. If you have an array of 30 character it will *always* be an array of 30 characters, in memory as in a file. But also remember that structures may actually contain bytes not declared by you, as the compiler might add padding between members or even after the last member. So in theory it's impossible to go exactly 30 bytes in either direction to get to the next member, instead use the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) macro to get the offsets of members.

Comment: I appreciate your attempts to help, so I'll try to explain as best as I can: I also need to be able to edit the students based on their ssn alone. I need to be able to go into the same file, students.db, find the ssn, and then change the data that precedes it (first and last). I'd like to be able to do this by effectively going back by 30 characters, and then changing it from there. Could I still do that even if the file shows that the data is only, say, 4 characters long (i.e, "john"), rather than the 30 that the first/last arrays demand?

Comment: @StrugglingStudent For that, I would rather suggest you read full structures. If you want to save space in memory, read the structures one by one. If you then find the structure with the correct SSN, modify the data in the structure, seek back the size of the structure itself, and write the full structure. That will be much easier, especially considering padding and such.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to implement that. Would an array of structs help?

Comment: @StrugglingStudent That would make it even easier, as then you could read the whole file into memory at once, search for the correct structure in the array, modify it, and then rewrite only that structure (at the correct place, which with a binary file is easy) or optionally rewrite the full array. You might need to check the size of the file (for example by opening it, seek to the end, and get the position), and allocate the array dynamically.